# can't access a file directory

Tags: java, file, io, directory, slash

This might be really nooby, but I'm trying to access a file directory so I can load all the images in it. For some reason when I input a file directory such as "/Images" it comes out as "\Images" when I create a new file and Windows can't find the directory because it's a backslash...

Code:

```
private final String imgDir =  "/Images";

File dir = new File(imgDir);

System.out.println(imgDir);
System.out.println(dir);

File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
  public boolean accept(File dir, String fname) {
     return fname.endsWith(".png") || fname.endsWith(".bmp") || fname.endsWith(".jpg");
  }
});
```

the print outputs are "/Images" and "\Images" respectively. files always comes out null because the dir is wrong. Any ideas why this could be?

EDIT:
Ok I got it to work. You guys were all right that I needed to used a relative path, but since it was IN the src folder I just needed to make it ".\src\Images" :D
Is it bad practice to do this? Should I just move the Images folder to the root project directory?

Comment: Can you do list (ls / dir) and show the directory structure you are accessing.

Comment: it's a folder called "Images" right inside the src folder of the project

Comment: I was guessing so. You are giving path as /Images ie absolute path. You should try "Images" directly or "./Image".

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference if I do "./Image". What does adding the period do?

Comment: thanks for the help, check the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows can't find the directory because it's a backslash

That's not the reason. Windows uses backslash itself.

> files always comes out null because the dir is wrong.

That would do it, for example if as per your comments you meant `./Images` but you actually coded `/Images`.

Answer (score 2):

Try composing your string using `File.separator` instead of explicit slashes, for example:
  `private final String imgDir = File.separator + "Images"`.

Comment: If I use File.separator both imgDir and dir are "\Images" but files is still null

Comment: Is "\Images" supposed to be an absolute or a relative path?  Perhaps you want ".\Images"?